# Adding a hyperlink on header image

Tags: napili, header

Is there any way to add a'hyperlink' on the header image, next to 'profile header' component. I tried adding an HTML component by dragging it, but unable to drag the component on the header image.

Answer (score 0):

The only way that you can achieve this, is creating a custom theme and adding a hyperlink in the custom header.

But, I've been trying to use something like Tokens for maintain the ability of change header image from builder, but its impossible, the only two ways that I found are:

1.- Create a static resource with header images.

2.- Hardcode the url of the header image uploaded using builder, if you use a naming convention for your images (like header, header1, header2, etc) its easy to reference this

If you want more info about custom themes check this:

[Create Custom Theme Layout Components for Communities](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_config_for_builder_theme_layout.htm)

[Styling with Design Tokens](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/tokens_intro.htm)